# R Matching based on mutiple columns

Tags: r, dataframe, matching

Let's say I have the following data set, which acts like the key

- x  y  value
- 1  2  10
- 1  1  20
- 2  1  30
- 1  1  20
- 2  3  200

I have another data with many many columns, 2 of them being x and y. I want to create a column value that matches to the key, e.g.

- x  y  value  and other columns
- 1  1  20
- 2  1  30
- 2  3  300

I can only use the match to make it work when matching one column. How do I extend to multiple column matching?

Comment: This seems like a `merge()` operation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `merge`, as @MrFlick suggested:

```
df.key <- data.frame(
  x=c(1,1,2,1,2),
  y=c(2,1,1,1,3),
  value=c(10,20,30,20,200))
##
df.add <- data.frame(
  x=c(1,2,2),
  y=c(1,1,3),
  value=c(20,30,300),
  a=rnorm(3),
  b=rpois(3,0))
##
> merge(
    x=df.key,
    y=df.add)
  x y value         a b
1 1 1    20 0.9246104 0
2 1 1    20 0.9246104 0
3 2 1    30 0.2685016 0
##
> merge(
    x=df.key,
    y=df.add,
    by=c("x","y"))
  x y value.x value.y          a b
1 1 1      20      20  0.9246104 0
2 1 1      20      20  0.9246104 0
3 2 1      30      30  0.2685016 0
4 2 3     200     300 -0.4174230 0
```

By default, this will join on the intersection of column names, like in the first example (`x`,`y`,`value`). Additionally, you can specify which columns to use from both `data.frame`s using `by=`, as in the second example. Or, you can get more specific by using `by.x=` and/or `by.y=`. See `?merge`.

**Edit:**

The problem is that `df.key` contains two rows where `x=1, y=1` is `TRUE`, so the row in `df.add` with `x=1,y=1` has to be duplicated in the join in order to preserve the data in `df.key`. I'm not sure how to make this adjustment elegantly (e.g. by specifying certain arguments to `merge`), but here's one approach:

```
R> merge(
    x=df.key[!duplicated(df.key[,c(1:2)]),],
    y=df.add)
  x y value          a b
1 1 1    20 -1.0185211 0
2 2 1    30  2.7507656 0
3 2 3   200  0.3986168 0
```

Comment: I need it where df.add initially does not have the value column, i.e.
df.add <- data.frame(
  x=c(1,2,2),
  y=c(1,1,3),  
  a=rnorm(3),
  b=rpois(3,0))

I need to the value row to be added

Comment: It will still work fine; as I noted above, `merge` will join on x and y (in this case) by default.

Comment: I believe I understand how it works now. I have one last question. When I the merge above, it takes every combination of rows, so it adds an extra row. Is there a command to add to the merge so that I get back as many rows in df.add after merging

Comment: @Nitin Krishnan I will update my answer to address this.